# Using destructors to detach events

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, destructor

Have noticed this code in the project:

So there is a custom TextBox:

```
public sealed class CoolTextBox : TextBox
{
    ...
    public CoolTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CoolTextBox);
        this.TextChanged += this.CoolTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    ~CoolTextBox()
    {
        this.TextChanged -= this.CoolTextBox_TextChanged;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have never wrote such type of constructions. But as far as i know and info from google says that you shouldn't trust the destructors, since they can be called anytime.

Should i just remove the destructor?

Comment: You only need to unsubscribe eventhandlers if the object that has the event that was subscribed to has a longer life time than the object that added the subscription. In this case both are the same object so there life times are equal. There is no need to unsubscribe.

Comment: Derived class can just override `OnTextChanged`. You do not need to subscribe to the event.

Comment: check WeakReference for such scenarios

Comment: Finalizer - will that evre be called? Because the way I see it.... the events will keep the object alive, hence finalizer is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalizers should only be used to clean up unmanaged resources. They can be called in any order and have a maximum execution time.

If you have any unmanaged resources, use the [Dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern).

If you don't have any unmanaged resources, implement `IDisposable`.

The events you should clean up are where the class you are disposing of is registered to an event on another object that will live longer.

If you can avoid using `event`s entirely, even better, as forgetting to unregister the handler can prevent garbage collection.